# Slow clock speed with Atmega328P AVR microcontroller on breadboard

Tags: microcontroller, clock-speed, atmega328p, usbasp

I have a small breadboard with an Atmega328p 28 pin microcontroller with a 16 MHz crystal and two 20 pF capacitors on it (similar to this demo: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard).

The difference with that demo is I am using a USBasp ISCP programmer to program the chip instead of an Arduino, and I was able to successfully program the infamous 'blink' program to my MCU and I couldn't be more happy.

However, instead of delaying for 1000 ms (1 second), I needed to change the parameter of my wait function to "20 ms" to achieve an on/off time of 1 actual second.

Is there something I'm missing here? Do I need to add anything to my circuit or perhaps change the capacitor values in order to fix the clock speed? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delay functions calculate the clock cycles by looking at the `F_CPU` macro. You have to set the `#define    F_CPU   16000000UL` so it matches the actual CPU speed.

That actual CPU speed is set by programming the fuses correctly. I think you forgot that step.

Comment: In particular, fresh 328Ps are configured to use the internal 8MHz oscillator, with an /8 divider, resulting in 1MHz, or 16 times slower than the expected Arduino-default.